# How to sell/buy rubles in EU?

Tags: foreign-exchange, rub-ruble

**Main question:** Is there a working service (or other way) to sell/buy rubles from EU?

**Minor question:** What price should I expect (relatively to official exchange rate)?

What I have tried:

- OANDA
- Local exchange offices
- Various other services online (they are many companies googleable to buy rubles, but at the end they do not offer that service when requested)

Comment: Isn't it illegal?

Comment: Two large countries that trade with Russia are China and India.

Comment: Ticker CEE, on the U.S. stock market, is holding Russian shares by number of shares but putting zero value on them. So that's an inexpensive buy-in.